# In what sense are Minkowski spaces with $(1,3)$ and $(3,1)$ signature isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, category-theory, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

There is no isometry between a $(1,3)$-signatured and a $(3,1)$-signatured Minkowski space, but in spite of this, they "look like" the same, for example, they have the same light cone. Is there any treatment (category) which defines a special kind of isomorphism so that $(1,3)$ and $(3,1)$-signatured Mikowski spaces are isomorhic (or the same)?

Edit: perhaps we should regard the Zeeman-topologies?

Comment: I think they're isomorphic as quadratic spaces. Two quadratic forms are isomorphic, when there's an invertible linear transformation $A$ such that $B(x,y)=B'(Ax,Ay)$. Here $A=-I$, I think. This justifies why they look like from some perspectives.

Comment: @stressedout You have such a map if you complexify (where A is multiplication by $i$), but I don't think such a map exists over the reals.  However, that's probably enough.  Perhaps, phrasing things slightly differently, we have that $B(x,y)=-B′(Ax,Ay)$, which says that everything is "the same" up to a sign.

Comment: @Aaron Oh, you're right. Well, what about $A=jI_{4\times 4}$ where $j=\sqrt{-1}$? I mean we can allow $A$ to be in $\mathrm{GL}_n({\mathbb{C}})$. Can't we? The theory of quadratic spaces should work over any field.

Comment: @stressedout That's what I meant when I said you had a map if you complexify.  But if you're working over the reals, you don't have $j$ to work with.

Comment: @Aaron OK. I agree with you.

Comment: @stressedout That's what I mean by complexification too.  The complex space can be seen as coming from the real space, and we have two different real (Minkowski) spaces that give rise to isomorphic complex spaces.  Yes, we could start from a complex space, but (1) you're implicitly getting your definition of the complex space by starting with the real one and extending, and (2) that ignores the problem that we are starting with real spaces.  The classification of binlinear forms, or Lie algebras, or a number of other things is easier over $\mathbb C$, but you need to go back when you're done.

Comment: @Aaron Yes, I agree with you. I immediately edited my answer and said that I agreed with you after I realized that we were working in $\mathbb{R}^4$ but our quadratic form had to be considered over complex numbers.

Comment: @mma I removed the "metric spaces" tag because the question really has little to do with metric spaces and analysis in general. Instead, I added quadratic forms and bilinear forms because they seem more relevant.

Comment: @stressedout Perhaps topology would be relavant (see the Zeeman-topologies of Minkowski spaces)?

Comment: @mma I don't disagree that it's relevant in a broad sense, but I think your question is rather of algebraic nature and the kind of isomorphism you are looking for is found in algebra, not topology or analysis. Check my answer, for example. But I might be wrong (because I don't have a background in physics) and there might be other interpretations that are equally valid or even more satisfying. As far as causality is concerned, the algebraic relation between these two spaces satisfies my curiosity. I don't know about yours.

Comment: @stressedout My motivation comes from physics. The Minkowski space is a model of the spacetime, and there is no difference (in the point of view of a physicist) between the two possibilities. So it would be nice to regard them the same in mathematics too. The complexification can be a correct answer, but it has no physical meaning, in contrast of the Zeeman-topologies.

Comment: @mma Yes, I understood your question. Just because I'm not a physicist it doesn't mean that I've never heard about flat space-time or the Minkowski space. :P So, I think it might be possible (and probably easy) to prove that both of these spaces are homeomorphic as topological spaces. Would that have any physical significance then?

Comment: @stressedout Yes, it's evdent to me, that they are homeomorphic, but homeomorphism is weaker (broader)  then isometry. I think that isometry doesn't change the physical meaning, in contrast to some non-isometric homeomorphism. But not only isometry is a physical equivalence but the transition from (1,3) signature to (3,1) too.

Comment: @mma But it's meaningless, at least mathematically, to talk about isometry here. We are not dealing with metric spaces here. The distance between two points of our space can be negative. The transition from inner products to more general bilinear forms that allow negative values too is shown in my answer. Maybe it's worth asking this question on physics.stackexchange.com as well. They will probably give you answers that are more satisfying for a physicist. But mathematically, it seems meaningless to talk about isometry between two spaces that are not metric spaces in the first place.

Comment: I think the correct mathematical context for your question should lead to answering the following question: when two Lorentzian (pseudo-Riemannian) manifolds are isomorphic? I think a natural idea would be to say that their bilinear forms should be related at each point of the tangent space. It's an extension of the isomorphism we define for Riemannian manifolds to cases where we don't have an inner product. Do you agree?

Comment: @stressedout Since you are a mathematician, you're probably right. But I think it's common to call the Lorentz-transformation a rotation, and a hyperbola (i.e. the set of vectors of norm 1 or -1) in a Minkowski space a circle, so I think, metric notions are commonly applied to pseudometric spaces, at least among phycicists and mathematical physicists. In this sense, the pseudo-metric preserving maps can be called "isometries".

Comment: @mma Note that all of these notions (rotations or conic sections) are rather concepts related to quadratic forms in general, instead of the more specific notion of a "metric". You can define rotations as orthogonal transformations with determinant $+1$. And all you need to be able to define an orthogonal transformation is a bilinear form that allows to define $\langle x, y \rangle$. Nothing more, nothing less. That kind of terminology might be good for physics, but it's confusing for mathematicians. And I'm not a mathematician really. I'm a math student.

Comment: I think I found the answer that is satisfactory for me. We extend a bit the notion of "pseudo-norm" to have values in a 1-dimensional vector space $I$ instead of $\mathbb R$. Then the (3,1) signiture belongs to a basis of $I$ and (1,3) belongs to another basis.

Comment: @mma Honestly speaking, I don't quite understand your last comment. I mean a $1$-dimensional vector space over what field? $\mathbb{R}$? If that's the case, then the vector space would be $\mathbb{R}$ itself. Maybe your idea is correct too and if you express it in more detail, it turns out to be a good mathematical reason for what you're looking for. But as it stands currently, I can't understand it. I got to go now, but I'll check the comments later because I like physics and its connection to mathematics, even though I don't understand it.

Comment: @stressedout A 1-dimensional vector space has no preferred notion of left or right, nor any canonical unit length. It's an $\mathbb{R}$-torsor, so an isomorphism with $\mathbb{R}$ is not canonically defined.

Comment: @KevinCarlson OK. But why does it have to be "canonical"? Any vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ as are any two $n$-dimensional vector spaces over the same base field after choosing a basis. I agree that choosing a basis means that the isomorphism is not canonical/natural or whatever, but why should it be? What specific meaning or significance does that have over just a non-canonical isomorphism? Is there a physical preference for canonical/natural transformations?

Comment: @stressedout This isn't about preferences, it's math: if you have a definite bilinear form on $\mathbb{R}^4$ valued in an abstract one-dimensional vector space, the best you can do is write it diagonally with all the diagonal entries either $v$ or $-v$ for some nonzero element $v$ of the vector space of values. So there's no way to distinguish $(1,3)$ from $(3,1)$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I don't understand how what you say is any different from the concept of changing the basis to be honest. I don't see the relevance.

Comment: @stressedout Well, even up to change of basis in the domain, you can distinguish $(1,3)$ from $(3,1)$. Ok, so I guess how I’d phrase this is that equivalence of bilinear forms up to change of basis in the domain is strictly stronger than equivalence that also allows postcomposition with an automorphism of the codomain.

Comment: @KevinCarlson OK. I'm starting to get some ideas now. I need more time to digest your comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $(V_1, q_1), (V_2, q_2)$ are $4$-dimensional vector spaces equipped with quadratic forms $q_1, q_2$ of signatures $(3,1)$ and $(1,3)$ respectively. Let $G_1, G_2$ denote the automorphism groups of the forms $q_1, q_2$, i.e. of linear transformations preserving the respective forms. Then the groups $G_1, G_2$ are isomorphic ($O(3,1)\cong O(1,3)$). More precisely, there exists an invertible linear map $L: V_1\to V_2$ such that:

1. $L_*(q_1)=-q_2$, i.e. for every vector $v\in V_1$ we have
   $$
   q_2(L(v))= -q_1(v). 
   $$
2. $L G_1 L^{-1}= G_2$.

Hence, the linear map $L$ preserves everything we care about when working with Lorentzian geometry.

One more thing: The same works for vector spaces equipped with quadratic forms of signatures $(p,q)$ and $(q,p)$, for instance, you can take the form $q_1$ to be positive-definite and $q_2$ negative-definite.

As for complexifying: This would be cheating since after that even forms of signatures $(3,1)$ and $(2,2)$ become isomorphic.

Comment: Yes: in words, the quadratic spaces are "anti-isometric", and their _isometry_groups_ are isomorphic by conjugation by any choice of anti-isometry.

Comment: Just for my own knowledge, how does $(3,1)$ and $(2,2)$ become isomorphic? What transformation would do that?

Comment: @stressedout: This is a basic fact of linear algebra:  All nondegenerate quadraic/bilinear forms on ${\mathbb C}^n$ are isomorphic. It is proven by finding orthonormal bases of two such forms and then defining an isomorphism by sending basis to basis.

Comment: Oh, OK. Can we say the same thing about quadratic forms over $\mathbb{R}$ too? Or does it fail because the reals are not algebraically closed?

Comment: @stressedout: Exactly! Over the reals you can always find an orthogonal basis but not necessarily orthonormal. Indeed, all you need is an algebraically closed field.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I learned so much from you and others on this post today. (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Minkowski space as $\mathbb{R}^4$ and equip it with the bilinear form $B(x,y)=x^tAy$ where $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

**Definition:** A vector space equipped with a quadratic form is called a quadratic space. In geometry, we like inner product spaces and they come equipped with a bilinear form that satisfies some extra properties like non-negativity, symmetry and non-degeneracy. Once we have a bilinear form $B$ on a vector space, we can induce a quadratic form $q: V\to \mathbb{F}$ on our vector space simply by considering $q(x)=B(x,x)$.

Now two bilinear forms $B_1$ and $B_2$ over an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ are called isomorphic when there exists an invertible transformation $T\in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F})$ such that $B_2(v,w)=B_1(Tv,Tw)$. Likewise, they're called anti-isomorphic if we instead have $B_2(v,w)=-B_1(Tv,Tw)$. You can formulate these definitions for quadratic forms as well.

In our case, it's easy to see that the different signatures $(3,1)$ and $(1,3)$ have quadratic forms that are anti-isomorphic by taking $T=I$. However, thanks to Moishe Cohen's answer, their automorphism groups turns out to be isomorphic by conjugation where conjugation is done using an anti-isomorphism. You can now see that the two version of the Poincare group defined using the two different signatures are isomorphic.